# Random Read Timeout in both preview and analysis modes - SonarQube 4.5.4LTS

Tags: java, postgresql, sonarqube

I upgraded from Sonar 4.4 to 4.5.4 LTS.

While running analysis in preview and normal analysis mode for java code using sonar runner(v2.4) from Jenkins, it throws random read time-out exceptions.

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.0.21 DB which is located on the same server as SonarQube and sonar-runner. Sonar has 400+ rules configured for java projects.

I've already set sonar.preview.readTimeout to a high value for preview analysis. I also tried doing a http-get prior to analysis to cache the initial fetch as suggested by another user. It did indeed reduce the frequency of read time-out issues. But once in a while it do fail.

DB is tuned for production environment. Kindly suggest any performance tuning strategy specific to sonarqube which can make a difference. I'm using a dedicated Linux(CentOS 5 32bit) server with Octa core processor n 12Gigs of RAM.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that you are facing the following limitation that we'll try to address in SonarQube 5.2: [SONAR-6604](http://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-6604)

=> I've added a reference to your post in the description of the ticket.

Comment: Thanks Fabrice.
Hope the fix will be pushed to the LTS version too :)